# Redirect 301 Url with date Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have much post with date like so /post/2016/02/14/come-cap.... I want replace date with nothing in C#.. So: /post/come-cap...
How can I make?
Can you help me?
Thanks
Fabrizio

Comment: I must to make if URL contains date you must to remove!

Answer (score 0):

Date tracking this way could be difficult, if your QueryString doesn't contain numbers then you can consider removing numbers in such scenarios like this:

```
if ("/post/2016/02/14/come-cap".Any(char.IsDigit))
{
  var output = Regex.Replace("/post/2016/02/14/come-cap", @"[\d]", string.Empty).Replace("////","/");
}
```